# Almost Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, gaussian-integral

> Solve the following integral:
>
> $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega_0 t ) e^{-i \omega t} dt$$
>   where $a, \omega_0 > 0$; $a, t, \omega_0, \omega \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

In other words, the Fourier transform of $e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega_0 t )$ is to be determined. As a first attempt, I tried to use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega_0 t ) \cos ( \omega t ) dt - i \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega_0 t ) \sin ( \omega t ) dt$$

Observing that the integrand function in the second integral is odd with respect to $t$, the integral reduces to

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega_0 t ) \cos ( \omega t ) dt$$

which can be split with [Werner's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities):

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at^2} \cos [(\omega_0 + \omega) t ] dt + \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-at^2} \cos [(\omega_0 - \omega) t ] dt$$

I tried to solve the first integral [by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), but it doesn't help (I don't know an antiderivative for $e^{-at^2}$; using the antiderivative of cosine leads again to an integral with $t e^{-at^2} \sin [(\omega_0 + \omega)t]$.

A direct solution for the two integrals in the RHS is provided in [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun) (10th printing, 1972, page 302, formula 7.4.6): but the intermediate steps are not showed there.

So, is there any way to proceed? Or another approach to follow?

Comment: It looks like something that should be Fourier transformed, but I haven't checked it.

Comment: @Lovsovs Yes, it is the Fourier transform of the function $e^{-at^2} \cos (\omega_0 t)$.

Comment: Have you tried www.symbolab.com ?

Comment: Okay, you were of course already aware of that! Btw, you write "I don't know an antiderivative for $e^{-at^2}$," but this is just the standard Gaussian integral (without limits it is the error function, with limits over $\mathbb{R}$ it is $\sqrt{\pi/a}$), but I'd expect you to already know this as well.

Comment: I suppose that the antiderivative can be expressed using the imaginary error function.

Comment: @toliveira No, thank you, anyway for this problem it can't show the steps.

Comment: @Lovsovs You are right; I knew it, but never found it about Fourier trasform, and I was looking for an explicit, possibly simple, function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Euler's formula to replace $\cos \omega_0t$ by 
$\displaystyle \frac{e^{i\omega_0t}+e^{-i\omega_0t}}{2}$ to get

$$I = \frac 12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-at^2}e^{-i(\omega-\omega_0)t}
\, \mathrm dt
+ \frac 12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-at^2}e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0)t}\, \mathrm dt = \frac{\mathcal F[e^{-at^2}](\omega-\omega_0) + \mathcal F[e^{-at^2}](\omega+\omega_0)}{2}$$
where $\mathcal F[g(t)](\omega) = G(\omega)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $g(t)$.